# Put label on a label in netbeans GUI builder

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, gui-builder

Trying desperately to put a label over another label in netbeans because the one label is acting as the background image and I want the label in the foreground to have a different image.

Every time i drag another label on top, the JFrame gets bigger and the label tries to slot down the side.

Here is what I've got (I want the label where the red circle in the middle is not on the right down the side):

[image]:

Comment: try  label.setBounds(int,int,int,int)........

Comment: That didn't seem to work @Benjamin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put one component on another, then you can use [Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html). 
A layered panel will let you specify that some child components should be layered above other child components.

[image]

**Update:**

An example:

```
JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();

JLabel lbOne= new JLabel("Label one");
JLabel lbTwo = new JLabel("Label two");

pane.add(lbOne, 0);
pane.add(lbTwo , 1);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? @Bahramdun Adil

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the JFrame layout to null..
If you use panel below set the panel layout also null hope its work for you .